# How can I make a sublist within a numbered list, and then return back to original entry of my numbered list?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I am trying to set up a sub-list within my numbered list in the typical format (e.g. the 1.a.i format), but I also would like to be able to continue writing within particular entry after providing a sub-list.

To illustrate:

```
1. text
    a. some other text
        i. some text about 1.a.i.
        ii. some other text about 1.a.ii.
        iii. some other text about 1.a.iii.
       some text about the sub-list above that is still part of section 1.a.
    b. some other text about section 1.b.
    c. some other text
2. new text
```

I do not know how to create the line `some text about the sub-list above that is still part of section 1.a.`. My attempts to hold the keys 'shift' and 'tab' after entering 'shift' and 'enter' while in section 1.a.iii. have only created 1.b., which I do not want. How can I create a sub-list within a certain section and then continue expand the same section without creating a new section?

Comment: Late to the game here, but I’ve had this question forever, and in general, not just for Word. I’m wondering if that aspect of text layout has a formal name; i.e. exactly as you describe, where after a list of items written within some heading at level N, one may continue with non-list text within that *same heading*, and not be forced into the *next* level N heading (with associated increment of heading number/letter). I’m wondering if there exists a typographical or page layout “term of art”, as it were, for such an an approach. I’d ask this as a question, but I’m not sure where!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new paragraph as usual, but then clear the numbering that's automatically inserted by either clicking **Numbering** in the **Paragraph** group on the **Home** tab of the ribbon or pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Then, for your example, because you want the paragraph aligned with the text in 1.a instead of the text in 1.a.iii, click **Decrease Indent** in the **Paragraph** group to adjust the indent.

Comment: This helped me in the end, but I should note, I had to be careful about at which line I clicked **Decrease Indent** on, otherwise my formatting would become completely messed up, and would not easily revert back.